# which sockets can be used to change cpus?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Since it's possible to replace cpus with the same sockets, for example lga 1150 sockets, would it work on bga sockets too? Or would the cpu go bad?

Comment: I ask this out of curiosity, not to antagonize you, is this your first engineering project?  Motherboards have a wide array of complexity, but I'd say to build one you'd have to be up to your neck in schematics.  To begin to answer your question, you would need reference docs of your motherboard layout and reference docs for the cpu...and at a minimum make sure the pins match up and they're meant to be interchangeable.  Also, you'll have to consider the thermal needs of that socket on that board.

Comment: I'm certain that with the right workshop you could replace a soldered-in BGA CPU  with a new one, but I would expect that you would ruin the old CPU by desoldering it, and it could not then be mounted again on another BGA board. The solder on the chip would have to be replaced. These are not user serviceable parts the way most consumer sockets are.

Comment: This is a really ambitious project. Start with creating a backboard first. Get the idea of hardware networking within a computer. And also start with a simpler (and less expensive) processor like a logic IC. Play around with Arduino's and FPGA's before you jump in at the deep end.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you replace bga socketed CPU?

You can **if you have the hardware to remove the CPU**.  You also have to replace the solder joints ( i.e. the ball grid array ) once you do.  As Frank suggests ICs that are soldered onto a PCB with a ball grid array are not easily serviced by the end user.  They can be replaced, there are tools in order to do, but they also require a certain level of soldering skill from the technician.

> Or would the cpu go bad?

Its highly likely without the skills required to do this you would damage the hardware.

Comment: this may be helpfui: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array#Difficulty_of_inspection

Comment: If there is something wrong with this answer feel free to vote accordingly but indicate how it can be improved